# Moduli Space of Flat connection over Homology 3-Shpere

Tags: connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

I'm trying to understand the space of flat connections over the trivial $SU(2)$ -bundle of a closed, oriented homology three-sphere (for the purpose of understanding the instanton Floer homology of it).

From now on I will just define the space of gauge equivalent classes of flat connections on it to be $R$.

Are the following facts correct and why?

1. The trivial connection is the only reducible connection.
2. $R$ is isolated generically (according to the perturbation of Chern-Simons functional)。 That is to say in the moduli space of gauge equivalent classes of connections, elements of $R$ are isolated. Generic here means specifically if we choose enough perturbation of Chern-Simons functional, its critical points will be considered as deformed flat connections, denoted as $R_h$ w.r.t. the perturbation $h$. $R_h$ is isolated.
3. $R$ is compact.

Comment: What do you mean by (2)? As written, it is totally unclear. What are your thoughts about the question and how much do you  know about moduli spaces of flat $SU(2)$-connections and their relation to spaces of representations of the fundamental group to $SU(2)$?

Comment: Cross-posted on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420384/moduli-space-of-flat-connection-over-homology-3-shpere).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the comment! I've editted the question. I know loosely that a flat connection gives you a holonomy map, but I don't see how the quotient be group action comes from.